# Calling a Partial View using view name vs full path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to know if there is any difference, in terms of load time, between the following partial view calls

```
@Html.Partial("MySharedView") 

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MySharedView.cshtml")
```

Could it be considered that in the first statement the view engine will scan all the possible default view paths and in the second it will go straight to the defined path without scanning?
If yes, would the second statement gain some rendering time improvement?

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` ultimately calls the `Find()` method of [ViewEngineCollection.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewEngineCollection.cs) which gets the collection of all view paths and loops through them. `/Views/yourController` will be checked before `/Views/Shared` but its so insignificant its not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a more efficient load time when using a full path over a named view, your suspicions are indeed correct.

Here's a good read on this very subject: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcinon/2011/08/16/optimizing-asp-net-mvc-view-lookup-performance/